# Double escaping hexadecimal characters ie \\x80 - \\xFF

Tags: php, regex

I have finally started to understand the context behind escaping hexadecimal characters such as `\x80`. The documentation talks about the [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), but I can also see that some regular expression use double backslashes such as `\\x80 - \\xFF`.

What's the difference between `\\x80 - \\xFF` and `\x80 - \xFF` when using something like preg_replace ?

Comment: It also depends on whether you use `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `preg_` functions, your string is parsed *twice* - first, by php compiler, and then by the PCRE engine. So if you have, for example:

```
preg_match("/\x80/"....)
```

the compiler turns it into

```
preg_match("/�/"....) // let � be chr(80)
```

and passes *this* to PCRE. When you have two slashes:

```
preg_match("/\\x80/"....)
```

the compiler turns the string into

```
preg_match("/\x80/"....)
```

and then it's the PCRE engine that converts this to the literal character `�`.

It doesn't make a difference in this particular case, but consider:

```
preg_match("/\x5B/"....)
```

after compilation

```
preg_match("/[/"....)
```

and PCRE fails, because of the dangling metacharacter `[`. Now if you escape the slash

```
preg_match("/\\x5B/"....)
```

it's compiled to

```
preg_match("/\x5B/"....)
```

which makes PCRE happy, because it understands that `[` should be taken literally.

How exactly php compiles your string depends on the quotes you use: double/single/heredocs/nowdocs. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for details. A simple rule of thumb is to use single quotes when possible, if you have to use doubles (for variable interpolation), escape everything twice, even if there's technically no need (e.g `"\\b$word\\b"`).

Comment: That explanation certainly helped me. I wish I could've accepted more than one "solution", but I can't... so I have to "accept" the previous answer that was just as helpful. Appreciated, in any case.

Comment: @Grateful: no prob, glad to hear it helped!

Comment: Actually, re-reading your answer seemed to shed even more light on the issue for me. So, I was forced to come back to your answer instead. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To write hex `x80`, you use `\` and that way you get `\x80`.
Now in PHP string `\` escapes special characters. In string `"$var"` PHP will try to insert variable `$var` in that string (because string uses `"`. To escape `$` you write `"\$var"` and output will be just simple string `$var`.
Now to write `\` in string (no matter if it uses `"` or `'`) you use same escaping character `\`. So it becomes `\\` to output `\`.

If you write `"\x80"` your output will be `"x80"` (without `\`). Than you escape `\` with another `\` => `"\\x80"` outputs `"\x80"`.

So to summarize everything:
`\x80` is hex character, and when you write it inside string, you write `\\x80`.

*Just some fun:*

PHP that outputs js function to alert `\x80`:

```
echo "function alertHex(){
    alert('\\\\x80 - \\\\xFF');
}";
```

Why 4 x `\`? First you escape PHP string to get `alert('\\x80 - \\xFF')`, that you escape JS string to get `\x80 - \xFF`.
Same with `preg_replace`: Allowed symbols: `\`, `$`, `a-z`, `[`, `]`: patern: `\\\$[a-z]\[\]`; `preg_replace('\\\\\$[a-z]\\[\\]', '', $str);`

Comment: Thank you for time and effort. It helped me reach the eventual answer.